# jquery perform something based on empty ([]) JSON string

Tags: jquery, json

Im getting returned JSON like this

```
{"d":{"questions":[],"stuff":"value"}}
```

how do I check for questions and do something if its blank/empty IE the [] with  nothing inside?

This doesn't work:

```
var msg = data.d.IsErrorExists;
var quetions = data.d.questions;
if (msg == 'false' && questions === '[]') {
        //do stuff based on msg=false and questions=[]
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the `length` of the array is greater than zero:

```
 if (questions.length){
 }
```

Comment: So if (msg == 'false' && questions.length) {//do something }?

Comment: probably `if (!msg && !questions.length)`

Comment: so that will check for NO msg and No qustions, just remove the first ! to check FOR msg and no questions right?